# Рисование кистью.

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация

- У меня есть массив точек размером 100х100, на каждую точку отводится 4 байта- (красный,зелёный,синий,альфа-канал). Этот массив представляет собой кисть, сложной формы (домик например).
- Есть также массив точек 1500х1500,(буфер) где на точку отводится 3 байта (по байту на красный,зелёный и синий).
- Ещё есть контекст устройства, для вывода

---

*Мой алгоритм:*

1. Каждая точка кисти переписывается в буфер с учетом альфа канала этой точки кисти. Т.е. переписывается каждый компонент в свой соответствующий компонент в буфере (компонентом подразумеваю каждый байт точки (кроме альфы)).
2. Пункт 1 повторяю 1000 раз, т.е. в буфер надо нарисовать 1000 кистей.
3. Далее вывожу буфер в контекст уст-ва с помощью WinApi функ-ии BitBlt().

---

*Вопрос:*

- Итак мы переписываем в буфер (кол-во точек кисти)х(кол-во выводимых кистей)=100х100х1000= **10млн пикселей**, А всего операций присвоения **10млн х 3**(т.к. RGB), **не считая вычислений**!!!!.

В итоге алгоритм выполняется около 3 сек. (что меня приятно удивило), но все же, не осудите за наглость, хотелось бы, чтобы работало это все со скоростью не более 0,5 сек, или даже 0,1сек.

Стоит ли ради этого перепысывать всё это на ассемблер? Или можно как-то оптимизировать алгоритм? Или же дело даже не в алгоритме, а в его реализации на языке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать sse или подобное. И обрабатывать не по одной точке за раз, а десятками. Плюс, подозреваю, Ваш алгоритм хорошо должен параллелиться. Так что, думаю, в раз 5-7 можно ускориться, если захотеть.

Comment: А как это, десяток за раз? ведь для каждой точки свой результат вычислений.

Comment: * Игнорировать пиксели кисти с альфой = 0.
* Хранить вариант кисти с цветами заранее перемноженными на свой альфа-канал